# How do I fix the initialize payment sheet error?

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I am getting this error even though I have initialized the payment sheet already.

Exception has occurred.
_$_StripeException (StripeException(error: LocalizedErrorMessage(code: FailureCode.Failed, localizedMessage: No payment sheet has been initialized yet. You must call `initPaymentSheet` before `presentPaymentSheet`., message: No payment sheet has been initialized yet. You must call `initPaymentSheet` before `presentPaymentSheet`., stripeErrorCode: null, declineCode: null, type: null)))

```
       //Initialize Payment Sheet
       await Stripe.instance
      .initPaymentSheet(
          paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
              paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntent?[
                  'client_secret'], //Gotten from payment intent
              style: ThemeMode.light,
              merchantDisplayName: 'testview',
              googlePay: gpay))
       .then((value) {});

       //STEP 3: Display Payment sheet
       displayPaymentSheet(context, onPaymentResult: onPaymentResult);
       } catch (err) {
       if (err.toString().contains('WebUnsupportedError')) {
       showMessage("Online payment not supported on web yet");
       } else {
       showMessage("Payment failed");
      debugPrint(err.toString());
      }
      onPaymentResult(false);
      }
      }

      displayPaymentSheet(BuildContext context,
      {required void Function(bool) onPaymentResult}) async {
      AppProvider appProvider = Provider.of<AppProvider>(context, listen: false);
      try {
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet().then((value) async {
      bool value = await FirebaseFirestoreHelper.instance
        .uploadOrderedProductFirebase(
            appProvider.getBuyProductList, context, "Paid");

    if (value) {
      onPaymentResult(true);
      Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
        appProvider.clearBuyProduct();
        appProvider.clearCartProductsFromFirebase();
        Routes.instance.pushAndRemoveUntil(
            widget: const CustomBottomBar(),
            context: context,
            material: false);
        });
         }
        });
        } catch (e) {
        showMessage("Payment cancelled!");
        onPaymentResult(false);
        }
         }
```

I am getting this error even though I have initialized the payment sheet already.

Exception has occurred.
_$_StripeException (StripeException(error: LocalizedErrorMessage(code: FailureCode.Failed, localizedMessage: No payment sheet has been initialized yet. You must call `initPaymentSheet` before `presentPaymentSheet`., message: No payment sheet has been initialized yet. You must call `initPaymentSheet` before `presentPaymentSheet`., stripeErrorCode: null, declineCode: null, type: null)))

```
       //Initialize Payment Sheet
       await Stripe.instance
      .initPaymentSheet(
          paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
              paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntent?[
                  'client_secret'], //Gotten from payment intent
              style: ThemeMode.light,
              merchantDisplayName: 'testview',
              googlePay: gpay))
       .then((value) {});

       //STEP 3: Display Payment sheet
       displayPaymentSheet(context, onPaymentResult: onPaymentResult);
       } catch (err) {
       if (err.toString().contains('WebUnsupportedError')) {
       showMessage("Online payment not supported on web yet");
       } else {
       showMessage("Payment failed");
      debugPrint(err.toString());
      }
      onPaymentResult(false);
      }
      }

      displayPaymentSheet(BuildContext context,
      {required void Function(bool) onPaymentResult}) async {
      AppProvider appProvider = Provider.of<AppProvider>(context, listen: false);
      try {
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet().then((value) async {
      bool value = await FirebaseFirestoreHelper.instance
        .uploadOrderedProductFirebase(
            appProvider.getBuyProductList, context, "Paid");

    if (value) {
      onPaymentResult(true);
      Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
        appProvider.clearBuyProduct();
        appProvider.clearCartProductsFromFirebase();
        Routes.instance.pushAndRemoveUntil(
            widget: const CustomBottomBar(),
            context: context,
            material: false);
        });
         }
        });
        } catch (e) {
        showMessage("Payment cancelled!");
        onPaymentResult(false);
        }
         }
```